youtube-dl-exec in typescript "not callable"
This is my code
import youtubeDl from 'youtube-dl-exec';

const run = async () => {
  const output = await youtubeDl('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6xKWiCMKKJg', {
    dumpSingleJson: true,
    noCheckCertificates: true,
    noWarnings: true,
    extractAudio: true,
    addHeader: ['referer:youtube.com', 'user-agent:googlebot'],
  });

  console.log(output);
};

run();


this is my tsconfig
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig",
  "extends": "@tsconfig/strictest/tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    // https://www.npmjs.com/package/@tsconfig/node20
    // https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/2000 -> can not inherit from multiple due to ts-node limitation
    "lib": ["es2023"],
    "module": "node16",
    "target": "es2022",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node16",

    "preserveWatchOutput": true,                      /* Whether to keep output files on successful compilation. */
    "sourceMap": true,                                /* Create source map files for emitted JavaScript files. */
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,            /* Ensure that casing is correct in imports. */
    "useUnknownInCatchVariables": true,               /* Default catch clause variables as 'unknown' instead of 'any'. */
    "noUnusedLocals": true,                           /* Enable error reporting when local variables aren't read. */
    "noImplicitReturns": true,                        /* Enable error reporting for codepaths that do not explicitly return in a function. */
    "outDir": "./dist",                               /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */
    "resolveJsonModule": true,                        /* Include modules imported with .json extension. */
  },
  "ts-node": {
    "esm": true, // «———— enabling ESM for ts-node
  }


this is the error I am getting:
This expression is not callable.
Type
typeof import('/Users/***/WORK/WLOS/***/***-video-translator-back-end-2/node_modules/youtube-dl-exec/src/index')
has no call signatures.


The code compiles with this error and runs correctly. How to get rid of the error ? I don't want to add ts-ignore.

Check type definitions, Sometimes, TypeScript may not recognize the types correctly, especially if the type definitions are missing or incorrect. You can try installing or updating the @types/youtube-dl-exec package to see if it provides the necessary type definitions.     npm install --save-dev @types/youtube-dl-exec
bash

@RaviChauhan thank you. The package has definitions by default. They are correct. There is something else.
